# ghostscript only create PDF1.7 not PDF/A

Tags: bash, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I try to create a PDF/A file out of many PDF/A-Files in the folder `pdf-files`.

```sh
gs -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile=Unsigned_Joined_Document.pdf ./pdf-files/*
```

But when I execute this, it gives me this error message and creates a PDF1.7 File.

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: UTF16BE text string detected in DOCINFO cannot be represented in XMP for PDF/A1, discarding DOCINFO
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Setting Overprint Mode to 1
 not permitted in PDF/A-2, overprint mode not set
```

I tried various questions on stack overflow but to no avail.

Comment: Well the back channel says it's discarding the problematic parts of the input file. There are problems with your command line (you haven't set the required information using a pdfa_def.ps file and you are using -sProcessColorModel instead of -sColorConversionStrategy). But you haven't supplied either the input or output files, so its basically impossible to give you any help. Note that Ghostscript doesn't accept wildcards in the filename like that so I'm surprised you're getting anything at all out. Make the file available and I'll look at the problem.

Comment: @KenS I am a first timer when it comes to ghostscript and pdf generation. Could you tell me more about the pdfa_def.ps file and which Arguments need to be defined in order to create a PDF/A. Because I think the issue here are various things which I missunderstood.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#PDFA Notice in the example command line 'PDFA_def.ps'. There's a 'template' version of that file in ghostpdl/lib/PDFA_def.ps, you **must** customise that appropriately, in particular you must set the /ICCProfile. However, that should not prevent pdfwrite producing a PDF/A file, it just won't be 100% valid. How are you determining that the file is not a PDF/A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on creating a PDF/A file is [here](http://ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#PDFA)

Notice in the example command line the inclusion of 'PDFA_def.ps', that's a file which you need to customise, and has PostScript code which does a few steps which are required to create a valid PDF/A.

There's a 'template' version of that file in ghostpdl/lib/PDFA_def.ps, you must customise that appropriately, in particular you **must** set the /ICCProfile (and you need to make sure it's the right profile; Gray, RGB or CMYK to match the ColorConversionStrategy).

However, failing to include that that should not prevent pdfwrite producing a PDF/A file, it just won't (in general) be 100% valid.